# How to make my implementation of GRU fast as nn.GRU

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I’m trying to build a GRU network using simpler blocks of nn. While using nn.GRU works really fast (with GPU), my "manual" version is slow, even though it should also run on GPU. I’m trying to understand why that is - and if there's a way to optimize it.

Here’s the nn.GRU version:

```
def __init__(self, in_dim, h_dim, out_dim, n_layers, dropout=0):
        self.rnn = nn.GRU(in_dim, h_dim, n_layers)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(h_dim, out_dim)
def forward_(self, input: Tensor, hidden_state: Tensor=None):
        output, hidden = self.rnn(input, hidden_state)
        layer_output = self.decoder(output)
        return layer_output, hidden
```

My "manual" version:

```
def __init__(self, in_dim, h_dim, out_dim, n_layers, dropout=0):
        params = dict()
        for i in range(n_layers):
            if i != 0:
                in_dim = h_dim
            params[f'L{i}W1'] = nn.Linear(in_dim, h_dim)
            params[f'L{i}W2'] = nn.Linear(h_dim, h_dim, bias=False)
            params[f'L{i}W3'] = nn.Linear(in_dim, h_dim)
            params[f'L{i}W4'] = nn.Linear(h_dim, h_dim, bias=False)
            params[f'L{i}W5'] = nn.Linear(in_dim, h_dim)
            params[f'L{i}W6'] = nn.Linear(h_dim, h_dim, bias=False)
        params['W7'] = nn.Linear(h_dim, out_dim)
        for param in params:
            self.add_module(param, params[param])
        self.params = params
def forward(self, input: Tensor, hidden_state: Tensor=None):
    if hidden_state is None:
            layer_states.append(torch.zeros(batch_size, self.h_dim, device=input.device))
    for i in range(self.n_layers):
        layer_input = layer_middle
        layer_middle = torch.zeros(batch_size, seq_len, self.h_dim, device=input.device)
        params = self.params
        for j in range(seq_len):
            x = layer_input[:, j, :]
            z = F.sigmoid(params[f'L{i}W1'](x) + params[f'L{i}W2'](layer_states[i]))
            r = F.sigmoid(params[f'L{i}W3'](x) + params[f'L{i}W4'](layer_states[i]))
            g = F.tanh(params[f'L{i}W5'](x) + r*params[f'L{i}W6'](layer_states[i]))
            layer_states[i] = z*layer_states[i] + (1-z)*g
            layer_middle[:, j, :] = layer_states[i]
        layer_middle = nn.Dropout(self.dropout)(layer_middle)
    layer_output = torch.zeros((batch_size, seq_len, self.out_dim), device=input.device)
    for j in range(seq_len):
        x = layer_middle[:, j, :]
        layer_output[:, j, :] = params['W7'](x)
```

Both work, but the 1st is much faster. [This](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/90ffab6e3713a40f47f4c9d3d3b16d56e83f97c4/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/RNN.cu#L239) (is what I assume) is the implementation of the first. I think I'm doing pretty much the same. I also call `.to(device)` on my model, so that everything will run on GPU.

Any ideas what might be the cause?

Comment: You are implementing in a high level AP (pytorch) what the link you provided solves at a low level (raw, highly optimized CUDA coda). Especially for recurrent neural networks, GPU code needs to be optimized because of the recurrent (i.e. non-parallel dependency). I would deem that the main reason. To get more into detail, you could add calls to time.time() and see where your code takes its time.

Comment: @Jan - thanks. But I wonder if there's any more differences? Can you implement this faster in pytorch?

Comment: No guarantees but I would say it's possible. I would probably start with pre-allocating all your calls to `torch.zeros` if possible because they cause (slow) dram memory access. You can reset those pre-allocations with `Tensor._zeros()`. For your inner-most loop, layers 1, 3, 5 and 2, 4, 6 all get the same input, so they could be put into a single layer and their output split up again, that may give you an advantage... Just some ideas... Before doing anything, I'd make sure to benchmark each operation, though...